# Why I'm getting "Parsing error: Unexpected token <" from ESLint in Vue components?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, eslint

I created a Laravel project and installed VSCode and all those necessary extensions. One of these is ESLint and it's working fine with JS file, but when I open a Vue component like (resources/js/component/ExampleComponent.vue), I get this error from ESLint:

"Parsing error: Unexpected token < eslint [1, 1]"

My `.eslintrc.js`file was generated using `./node_modules/.bin/eslint --init` and answering the questions.

I already googled and found this solution:

`npm install babel-eslint --save-dev`

and add this to `.eslintrc.js`:

`parser: "babel-eslint"`

but it doesn't work anyway, the error stay there.

Here is my `ExampleComponent.vue` (unmodified from Laravel):

```
<template> (ESLint error here: "Parsing error: Unexpected token < eslint [1,1]")
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        Example Component
                    </div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        I'm an example component.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

Here is my `.eslintrc.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es6: true,
  },
  extends: 'airbnb-base',
  globals: {
    Atomics: 'readonly',
    SharedArrayBuffer: 'readonly',
  },
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2018,
    sourceType: 'module',
    parser: "babel-eslint",
  },
  plugins: [
    'vue',
  ],
  rules: {
  },
};
```

Comment: Seems like you didn't install the Vue plugin

Comment: Are you saying about eslint-plugin-vue? When I used eslint --init, it installed the vue plugin for me. I have this in my package.json file (related to ESLint):

"babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
"eslint": "^5.16.0",
"eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^13.1.0",
"eslint-config-google": "^0.12.0",
"eslint-plugin-babel": "^5.3.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.17.2",
"eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.2.2",

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you need the plugin [`eslint-plugin-vue`](https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue), and to set your `.eslintrc.js` configuration to one of the [bundle configurations](https://eslint.vuejs.org/user-guide/#usage):

- `"extends": ["plugin:vue/base"]`
- `"extends": ["plugin:vue/essential"]`
- `"extends": ["plugin:vue/strongly-recommended"]`
- `"extends": ["plugin:vue/recommended"]`

You can read [more about `eslint-plugin-vue` here](https://eslint.vuejs.org/user-guide/#faq) - [here is a reference](https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/issues/746) for a similar issue you are having.

Hope this helps!

***EDIT:*** this is an `eslint` config from a `vue cli` project:

```
module.exports = {
  "root": true,
  "env": {
    "node": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "plugin:vue/essential",
    "eslint:recommended"
  ],
  "rules": {},
  "parserOptions": {
    "parser": "babel-eslint"
  }
}
```

Comment: As I'm using Airbnb base, I just put "plugin:vue/recommended" and "eslint:recommended" on my .eslintrc.js and now it's working. Thank you.

Comment: Using a .eslintc file in my root with the above as JSON fixed my issue.